# Click on button call item

Tags: java, android

When you click the button. I want an item to be called and executed

my xml file:

```
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item android:title="Item"
        android:id="@+id/nav1" />

    <item android:title="Item"
        android:id="@+id/nav2"/>

    </group>
 </menu>
```

my simple menu item:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav1) {


    } else if (id == R.id.nav2) {


    }
```

my button:

```
 final Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mybutton);
     button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
           //when click on this button i want executed item with id nave1
         }
     });
```

when click on the button (mybutton) must call item and executed it

Comment: Please explain exactly what you want, I see in the comments that you are adding more requirements (Item selected, Scroll to set item visible). As for me, I would see that as a different question, that is probably already existing on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `NavigationView.setCheckedItem()`

```
final Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mybutton);
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav1);
    }
});
```

Or call `onNavigationItemSelected()` yourself.

```
final Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mybutton);
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        onNavigationItemSelected(navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav1));
    }
});
```

Comment: it worked but my menu item dont show the item is selected and not scrolled to the position because i have many items

Comment: @mody use `android:checkableBehavior="single"` in your `group` xml.

Answer (score 0):

Its  simple you can do it this way,create a method then call it anywhere u want.

```
private void yourMethodName() {
        // do your stuff here
    }
```

No call this

```
@Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav1) {
     yourMethodName();

    } else if (id == R.id.nav2) {


    }
```

and then in button click ,

```
final Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mybutton);
     button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
           yourMethodName();
         }
     });
```

Comment: i want click on item for to causes 1- for go to position because i have many iten 2-for show the item is selected

Comment: pass the position in the method

Comment: I did not understand you